# Не знаю как лучше сверстать такие карточки может подскажет кто в какую сторону лучше посмотреть, спасибо

Tags: html, css

[image: вот карточки]

```
<section class="price">
  <div class="container">
      <h2 class="price__title title">Стоимость и оплата</h2>
      <div class="price-grid">
          <div class="price-grid__card">
              <div class="price-grid__subtitle">VDS</div>
              <div class="price-grid__descr"></div>
              <div class="price-grid__cost"></div>
              <button class="btn"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="price-grid__card">
              <div class="price-grid__subtitle">VDS</div>
              <div class="price-grid__descr">
                  
              </div>
              <div class="price-grid__cost"></div>
              <button class="btn"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="price-grid__card">
              <div class="price-grid__subtitle">VDS</div>
              <div class="price-grid__descr"></div>
              <div class="price-grid__cost"></div>
              <button class="btn"></button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `.price-grid { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center}` Что именно не получается?

Comment: именно то, что находится внутри карточки (ram - 8gb, ssd - 30gb) как это правильней будет разбить?

Comment: Разбей на два `span`'а во вложенном флексбоксе строки карточки (с `justify-content: space-between`, или с `margin-left: auto` у второго span'a - как будет удобнее).

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.card {
  --card-gradient: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  --card-gradient: #5e9ad9, #e271ad;
  --card-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0.05rem 0.1rem 0.3rem -0.03rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--card-gradient), white max(9.5rem, 27vh));
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  border-radius: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height: max(10rem, 30vh);
  aspect-ratio: 4/3;
  mix-blend-mode: var(--card-blend-mode);
}

.card img~* {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.card> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card:hover,
.card:focus-within {
  --card-gradient: #24a9d5 max(8.5rem, 20vh);
}


/* Additional demo display styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, avenir next, avenir, helvetica neue, helvetica, Ubuntu, roboto, noto, segoe ui, arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #e1faf1;
}

.card h3 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.card a {
  color: inherit;
}

.card-wrapper {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30ch, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 120ch;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="card-wrapper">
  <li class="card">
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611916656173-875e4277bea6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400' alt=''>
    <h3><a href="">A Super Wonderful Headline</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amit</p>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611083360739-bdad6e0eb1fa?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400' alt=''>
    <h3><a href="">What a Fantabulous Title!</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amit</p>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613230485186-2e7e0fca1253?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=400' alt=''>
    <h3><a href="">Positively Terrific Title</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amit</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```